# Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be instantiated

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, filesystems

I am trying to save a model learning to S3 from my Spark Standalone cluster. But I have this error :

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2631)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2650)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1853)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.<init>(EventLoggingListener.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:529)
at ALS$.main(ALS.scala:32)
at ALS.main(ALS.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/event/ProgressListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.amazonaws.event.ProgressListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more
```

I have added Hadoop-aws aws-sdk in extraClassPath in spark-defaults.conf

What I have tried so far : I send my spark-submit with a fat jar compiled by sbt assembly (I have also added those dependencies in the sbt). My AWS Credentials are exported in the master environnement

Any idea on where I need to explore to fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an aws class, so you are going to need to make sure your CP has *the exact set of `aws-java`  JARs your `hadoop-aws` JAR was built against.

[mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws) lists those dependencies.

I have a project whose whole aim in life is to work out WTF is wrong with blobstore connector bindings, [cloudstore](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/releases). You can use that in spark-shell or real spark queries to help diagnose things.

Comment: Thank you I will you try your project. I have added `Hadoop-aws` and `aws-java` in `spark.driver.extraClassPath` is this what you are talking about ?

Comment: Your tool showed me an error : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AUtils`

Comment: S3AUtils? That should be in hadoop-aws JAR. That means the classpath the tool is getting doesn't contain that. For spark, put things in $SPARK_HOME/jars, alongside the other hadoop-* JARs it has

Comment: I believe an example of compatible jars is covered in this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415928/spark-s3-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-org-apache-hadoop-f

Comment: Natalie -not really, That answer looks at the s3n connector which was already deprecated in spark 2.7 and depends on the jets3t library. the S3A one uses the aws SDK

Answer (score 0):

I faced so many problems extending for IAMcredential, etc, I solved this issue by downloading a hadoop version that matches with my spark version, then I copied the hadoop-common jar into spark jar folder. The hadoop-common must be the same version with hadoop-aws jar, in my case hadoop-aws-3.2.2.jar and hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar.