# Spark + s3 - error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a spark ec2 cluster where I am submitting a pyspark program from a Zeppelin notebook.  I have loaded the hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar and aws-java-sdk-1.11.179.jar and place them in the /opt/spark/jars directory of the spark instances.  I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException

Why is spark not seeing the jars?  Do I have to have to jars in all the slaves and specify a spark-defaults.conf for the master and slaves?  Is there something that needs to be configured in zeppelin to recognize the new jar files?

I have placed jar files /opt/spark/jars on the spark master.  I have created a spark-defaults.conf and added the lines

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key     [ACCESS KEY]
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key     [SECRET KEY]
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl           org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.driver.extraClassPath        /opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar:/opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.11.179.jar
```

I have zeppelin interpreter sending a spark submit to the spark master.

I have also placed the jars in the /opt/spark/jars in the slaves too but did not create a spark-deafults.conf.

```
%spark.pyspark

#importing necessary libaries
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark import SQLContext
from itertools import islice
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# add aws credentials
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "[ACCESS KEY]")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "[SECRET KEY]")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")

#creating the context
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

#reading the first csv file and store it in an RDD
rdd1= sc.textFile("s3a://filepath/baby-names.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))

#removing the first row as it contains the header
rdd1 = rdd1.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
lambda idx, it: islice(it, 1, None) if idx == 0 else it
)

#converting the RDD into a dataframe
df1 = rdd1.toDF(['year','name', 'percent', 'sex'])

#print the dataframe
df1.show()
```

Error thrown:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 10.11.93.90, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: https://www.philipphoffmann.de/post/spark-shell-s3a-support/

Answer (score 21):

I was able to address the above to make sure I had the correct versions of the hadoop aws jar per the version of spark hadoop that I was running, downloading the correct version of `aws-java-sdk`, and lastly downloading the dependency jets3t library

[image]

In the /opt/spark/jars

```
sudo wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.30/aws-java-sdk-1.11.30.jar
sudo wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.3/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
sudo wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.4/jets3t-0.9.4.jar
```

Testing it out

```
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", [ACCESS KEY ID])
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", [SECRET ACCESS KEY] )
scala> val myRDD = sc.textFile("s3n://adp-px/baby-names.csv")
scala> myRDD.count()
res2: Long = 49
```

Comment: I think the jar has changed a little since this was posted, I had to use the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` jar instead of the `aws-java-sdk` jar. This is a good resource https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500698/3614578

Answer (score 14):

If S3 access is by assume_role from local cluster then below worked for me.

```
import boto3
import pyspark as pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='profile_name')
sts_connection = session.client('sts')
response = sts_connection.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam:::role/role_name', RoleSessionName='role_name',DurationSeconds=3600)
credentials = response['Credentials']

conf = pyspark.SparkConf()

conf.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0')  //crosscheck the version. 

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', credentials['AccessKeyId'])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', credentials['SecretAccessKey'])
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.session.token', credentials['SessionToken'])
url = str('s3a://data.csv')

l1 = sc.textFile(url).collect()
for each in l1:
    print(str(each))
    break
```

keep below proper version of class files also in $SPARK_HOME/jars

1. jets3t
2. aws-java-sdk
3. hadoop-aws

I prefer to delete unwanted jars from ~/.ivy2/jars

Answer (score 9):

#### From the official `Hadoop` troubleshooting [documentation](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md):

```
   ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem

   These are Hadoop filesystem client classes, found in the `hadoop-aws` 
   JAR. An exception reporting this class as missing means that this JAR 
   is not on the classpath.
```

#### To solve this problem first need to know what is `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a`:

In the [Hadoop website](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html), it explains in detail what `Hadoop-AWS module: Integration with Amazon Web Services` is. And the [prerequisite](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#getting_started) to use it is having these two jars installed under `/Spark/jars` directory:

1. `hadoop-aws` Jar
2. `aws-java-sdk-bundle` Jar

[image]

#### When downloading these jars, make sure two things:

1. `Hadooop` version matches with `hadoop-aws` version, a `hadoop-aws-3.xx.jar` works for a `hadoop-3.xx`
2. `aws SDK` for `Java` matches the `Java` version installed. Check this [official document](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/developer/the-aws-sdk-for-java-will-no-longer-support-java-6/) from `AWS` on exact version requirements.

For more troubleshooting, can always refer to the official `Hadoop` troubleshooting [documentation](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md):

Comment: Can you also provide the download links please.

Comment: A simple Googling would do it, and select the version that best suits you. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle

Comment: Thank you, is there a guide that tells use which version is compatible with the version of hadoop we have installed on our computers?

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

My system config:

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
python3.7.7 
openjdk version 1.8.0_252
spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7

1. Configure PYSPARK_PYTHON path:
   add following line in $spark_home/conf/spark-env.sh

   export PYSPARK_PYTHON= python_env_path/bin/python
2. Start pyspark

   pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.760,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.760 : depends on jdk version
   hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.0: depends on your hadoop version
   s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: depends on your s3 location

3.Read data from s3

```
df2=spark.read.parquet("s3a://s3location_file_path")
```

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54241420/11768156)

Answer (score 1):

Each hadoop version should match aws-java-sdk-...jar,  hadoop-aws-...jar.

And every aws-java-sdk version matched with hadoop-aws-..jar (it does not mean the same number).

For example ( aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar, hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar are pair versions).

Lastly you should enroll the s3 domain in the hive.cnf configuration file.

Comment: an example of how to check this would have been nice

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works in the above then do a cat and grep for the missing class. High possibility that the Jar is corrupted.
For example, if you get class AmazonServiceException not found, then do a grep where the jar is already present as shown below.

`grep "AmazonServiceException" *.jar`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to this file `hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>***</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>***</value>
</property>
```

Inside the Hadoop installation directory, find aws jars, for MAC installation directory is `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/`

```
find . -type f -name "*aws*"

sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/
sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/
```

[Credit](https://github.com/CoorpAcademy/docker-pyspark/issues/13#issuecomment-367988019)