# Error reading data from S3 on EC2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I'm trying to read from an s3 bucket by

```
data = spark.read.parquet("s3a://my-bucket/data")
```

but I'm getting an error like this:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 stores = spark.read.parquet(STORES_PATH)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in
> parquet(self, *paths, **options)
> 351         self._set_opts(mergeSchema=mergeSchema, pathGlobFilter=pathGlobFilter,
> 352                        recursiveFileLookup=recursiveFileLookup)
> --> 353         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
> 354
> 355     @ignore_unicode_prefix
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in
> **call**(self, *args)    1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1304         return_value
> = get_return_value(
> -> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1306     1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a,
> **kw)
> 126     def deco(*a, **kw):
> 127         try:
> --> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
> 129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
> 130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
> get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
> 327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
> 329             else:
> 330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.parquet. :
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found  at
> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)   at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)     at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)    at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:755)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found  at
> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
> ... 25 more

I couldn't solve the problem. Can someone help?
using pyspark=='3.0.1'
awscli='1.19.9'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark + s3 - error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415928/spark-s3-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-class-org-apache-hadoop-f)

Comment: no i checked it before posting.